# How can I get a light font weight in Fluent UI v9?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

It seems that Fluent UI v9 has bold font weights, but no light font weights. (See [Fonts](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/theme-fonts--page).) Does anyone know why this is and if there's a workaround to get the effect of a light font weight?